# Conditional for Post Format

Tags: php, conditional-tags, post-formats

I want to to show a specific content on the top of each post (on single page) depending of the post-type.

If it's `normal`, show something, if it's `gallery`, show another.

By now the code is like this:

```
<?php
    if  (has_post_format( 'post-format-normal' , $post_id )) {
        <div class="post-image-section section" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $single_post_image_url ?>);">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('single-post-image'); ?>
            <?php if ( !empty(get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt) ) : ?>
                <div class="flex-caption-container">
                    <p class="flex-caption"><?php echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; ?></p>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
        </div>
    } elseif ( has_post_format( 'post-format-gallery' , $post_id )) {
        <?php flexslider('index-post-image'); ?>            
    }
?>
```

But it's not working, looks like there is a typing error on the code... I want that if the post type is `gallery`, to show the flexslider, and if it's `normal`, show the post_thumbnail...

How to achieve that?

Comment: Where does `'post-format-normal'` come from?

Comment: I believe thats the default post format type? If the author has not selected anyother else i guess that this is the one choosen, like a default

Comment: @lucasmx: Default post_types are `post` & `page`, not "normal". [Details Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) :(

Comment: From your comment below: "*the problem im having it that because the conditional content i wish to use has HTML and PHP codes so when i try to render the website says that there is errors on the code*": can you please **edit your question** to include the **error message text**? Very likely, these are just PHP syntax errors (outside WPSE scope). Strip out the code down to the conditional statements, and make sure they're working; then add back your content piece-by-piece.

Comment: Chip the error starts at the first line of the code... i already managed to fix this, thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no "default" post format type, though internally in core, a post that has no post format assigned is usually referred to as *standard*. So, your first conditional will return `false` using `post-format-normal` because there is no such post format - but would still return false using `post-format-standard`.

You could reverse the conditional, and check for gallery post format first. Note that you could use either [`'gallery' == get_post_format()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format) or [`has_post_format( 'post-format-gallery' )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_format). (Personally, I find `get_post_format()` to be a bit more intuitive.)

In any case, you would reverse the conditional like so:

```
if ( has_post_format( 'post-format-gallery' ) ) {
    flexslider('index-post-image');       
} else {
    // Fallback output here
}
```

Note that you also have syntax errors in your code, such as nested PHP tags.

Comment: The problem im having it that because the conditional content i wish to use has HTML and PHP codes so when i try to render the website says that there is errors on the code

Answer (score 0):

First of all your problem I think is `$postid` variable, where are you setting it?

The code should be putted after `the_post();`.

After that consider that post format [are just taxonomies](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112504/post-formats-template/112645#112645), so even if you can use, for sure, `has_post_format()` if you want to show one different thing for every format probably is better use just <del>`get_the_terms`</del>(edited after @ChipBennett comment) `get_post_format` with a `switch`, but this is just an opinion.

You have also to consider that (as said in the above linked answer) there is no post format 'normal': a post format normal means no post format.

If you have some html/php mixed content can be hard and less readable correctly write code in the condition statement, so why dont create some template parts and use them?

Something like:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

  get_template_part( 'before-single', get_post_format() );

endwhile; endif;
```

After that you can create in your theme (or child theme) folder the files:

- before-single.php
- before-single-post-format-chat.php
- before-single-post-format-aside.php
- before-single-post-format-link.php
- before-single-post-format-chat.php
- before-single-post-format-audio.php
- before-single-post-format-video.php
- before-single-post-format-image.php
- before-single-post-format-quote.php
- before-single-post-format-status.php

Of course, you are **not** required to create all of this files, when the file for the current post format does not exist, the file `before-single.php` will be used.

In thes files you can freely use all the html and php code you want...

Comment: Why not just use `get_post_format()` for `$format`?

Comment: Because I didn't remember it exists.. :) (ok, I admit I hate post format and never use them, so I'm not familiar with the related functions) @ChipBennett

Comment: nice, but the problem im having it that because the conditional content i wish to use has HTML and PHP codes so when i try to render the website says that there is errors on the code

Comment: @lucasmx you can out html and php code inside the conditional statement, but is a bit harder and less readable, so I think is better create some template files and use them to write you content. See the edit on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, thank you for all the help, As i said the problem was PHP syntax which was causing render errors. As i was mixing PHP with HTML content i didnt knew how to properly write.

Here is the solution i found:

```
<?php  if( has_post_format( 'gallery' )) {  
flexslider('index-post-image'); 
}  else {?>  
<div class="post-image-section section" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $single_post_image_url ?>);">
            <a href="$the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('single-post-image') ?>
            <?php if ( !empty(get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt) ) : ?>
                <div class="flex-caption-container">
                    <p class="flex-caption"><?php echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; ?></p>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </a>
        </div>
<?php  }?>
```